# Hierarchy of value classes in Scala?

Tags: scala, value-class

I have defined the following class hierarchy where I want to restrict the the type parameter to be conformable with `Double`...

```
sealed abstract class Quantity[-T](value: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Double)

case class DiscreteQuantity(value: Long) extends Quantity[Long](value)

case class ContinuousQuantity(value: Double) extends Quantity[Double](value)
```

...is it possible to re-write the above hierarchy so that the concrete types are value classes?  From the docs I know that value classes can not be extended, so that rules out having `Quantity` inherit from `AnyVal`.  In order for concrete classes to inherit from `AnyVal` I need to make `Quantity` a trait, which is fine, but then I lose the contra-variant annotation on the type parameter.

Thoughts?

Comment: The code you start from doesn't work: "Cannot prove that Long <:< Double". `<:<` doesn't include weak conformance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but as I said in the comment: `<:<` and `<:` don't include weak conformance, so basically only `Quantity[Double]` can exist.

```
sealed trait Quantity[-T <: Double] extends Any { 
  protected[this] def value: T 
}

case class ContinuousQuantity(value: Double) extends AnyVal with Quantity[Double]
```